# Spring Data query to get concrete class with Discriminator

Tags: java, inheritance, spring-data, discriminator

i have this classes

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "processType")
public abstract class BaseProcess extends BaseModel {

}

@Entity
public class MainProcess extends BaseProcess {

}

@Entity
public class SubProcess extends BaseProcess {

}


@Entity
public class Tank {

    @Column
    private Long id;

}


@Entity
public class TagAddress {

    @Id
    private Long id

    @ManyToOne
    private BaseProcess process; 

    @ManyToOne
    private Tank tank;  

}

public interface TagAddressDao extends JpaRepository<TagAddress, Long> {

    @Query("FROM TagAddress WHERE tank.id = ?1 AND process.processType = 'MainProcess' ")
    List<TagAddress> findMainProcessByTankId(Long tankId);

    @Query("FROM TagAddress WHERE tank.id = ?1 AND process.processType = 'SubProcess' ")
    List<TagAddress> findSubProcessByTankId(Long tankId);

}
```

i got this error

> org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: processType ...

How do i filter by concrete class MainProcess and SubProcess in TagAddressDao?

something like i can do "instanceof MainProcess" or "instanceof SubProcess"